# how do I move multiple times between the same page in PHP?

Tags: php, forms

I am a PHP beginner and I am trying to write a facebook app that will ask a questionnaire for random friends.

I tried that for each friend a following info is presented in one page:

1. photo and name
2. questionnaire + submit

But apparently, all random friends were shown together:

```
for ($i=1; $i<= $num_Of_Friends ; $i++){
    require('friendPhotoAndName.php');
    require('questannaire.php');

}
```

Can you please suggest me how to fix that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

updated link

> - **demo:** https://so.lucafilosofi.com/how-do-i-move-multiple-times-between-the-same-page-in-php/

hope this help:

Comment: can you please suggest the best way you thought of?

Comment: see the updated code, note: each function goes presumably in it's required php page, but you can put both in one file.

Comment: I don't want to be rude but can you please add also the first solution you suggested? I would like to learn from both...this is incredible

Comment: Hi again - this solution shows all of the friends in the same page... I can I show them each friend in a different page?

Comment: demo & source http://aseptik.net/php5/demo/how-do-i-move-multiple-times-between-the-same-page-in-php/

Comment: you welcome Yoni ;), PS: download the source again cause i have made a little fix on points calculation. ;)